# Subsonic 2.2 InnerJoin Across Two Databases

Tags: subsonic, subsonic2.2, multiple-databases

Can anyone provide an example of how to join across two schemas using subsonic 2.2.

This doesn't work:

SqlQuery qu = new Select("*")
                    .From(NorthwindLeads.Lead.Schema)
                    .InnerJoin(Northwind.StatsMap.SourceIdColumn, NorthwindLeads.Lead.SourceIdColumn);

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do this in subsonic that I'm aware of. I would recommend adding a view to your database which returns the data you want from the other schema and then joining to the view in your subsonic query.